# Homebrew install: Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1

Tags: ruby, git, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I ran the following command on terminal (Mac El Capitan)

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and got the following error message:

```
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1
```

Additionally tried:

```
sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

then the two commands above.

Any idea how to install Homebrew?

`brew is not recognized` and `ruby version 2.0.0`, `git version 2.7.4`

Comment: Deleting folder `/usr/local/Homebrew` and retrying (once) was good enough on macOS Big Sur 11.2.

Comment: I had the same problem after an aborted install

I used `find / -name "brew" 2> /dev/null` to find every brew data and rm -rf'd it, in particular `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew`.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

After a few hours of research and brute force I learned the issue was due to git not being configured properly.  Some articles suggested downgrading your git or reinstalling all together.  However, I resolved the issue just by adding the following

```
git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com
```

Then remove the `cellar` and `homebrew` directories from `/usr/local` and re-try the installation.

Comment: Just deleting the `cellar` and `homebrew` directories did the trick for me. (for me above error occurred because my machine shutdown during the installation)
Thank you very much for the answer @anm .

Comment: For me only deleting the `Homebrew` folder was more than enough :)

Comment: For Apple silicon (arm64) i.e. M1 chips, @anm answer worked for me but only after doing 

`sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew` 

and then retry 

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

I came to this by checking the contents of the install script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh

Comment: After following the suggested steps: `zsh: command not found: brew`

Comment: I just removed Cellar and Homebrew folders from /usr/local then reinstall homebrew.. works for me 100%

Comment: Maybe this changed recently, but note that in the latest version of brew, the folders are `Cellar` and `Homebrew` (with capital letters)

Comment: @Cato 's answer is worked for me. thanks.

After following his steps, I did this:

    echo '# Set PATH, MANPATH, etc., for Homebrew.' >> /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
    echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> /Users/USERNAME/.zprofile
    eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

Answer (score 36):

1. create a file named `run.sh`
2. add this:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/brew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
```

3. run the file using `sh run.sh`

Or, just run all these commands manually one by one.

Comment: good answer, and for mac m1 Big Sur, add another line `rm -rf /opt/homebrew`

Comment: This work for me. If you also facing issues on [!] Error installing XXX while executing pod install. Try this answer. Thanks for saving my day

Comment: This worked for me executing @ashdaily commands, addindo `sudo` to last command and then the @Sinux command too. I'll put down the complet command set for being eaier to read.

Comment: This did it for my M1 mac

Comment: this didn't work for me. I have an M1 mac. I was using version 11, I have updated the big sur and started to use the 12.1 version. And the problem is solved now, I installed brew without any issue.

Answer (score 16):

@ashdaily commands worked for me, addindg `sudo` on last command and then executing also the @Sinux command too:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/brew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew
rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Answer (score 16):

Fastest and easiest way is to uninstall Homebrew by following command -

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

and after this, fresh install of Homebrew by following command -

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Comment: This worked for me when I was getting the "Not a valid ref" error

Answer (score 7):

Steps to fix it on **Big Sur (2021)**:

1. `git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com`
2. Remove the cellar and homebrew directories from `/usr/local`
3. Re-try the installation

Works for me on **Big Sur**.

Answer (score 5):

To fix the issue on Monterey:

```
1. sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/
2. git config --global user.email username@example.com
```

After executing the steps, try back the installation

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this issue for Apple silicon (arm64) M1 chips by running following commands:

1. ```
   sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
   ```
2. ```
   /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

- New home-brew will installed in `/opt/homebrew/` folder.
- If some errors happened at installation you need to reinstall all.
- Try to clean all trashes with `sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/` command
- Tested and It's worked (12 September 2021)

Also, may you need to configure `git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com`

Answer (score 2):

just do this little code

```
rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/core) # because you can't brew untap homebrew/core
brew tap homebrew/core
```

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure you disable any ISP related 'child safe' settings.**

I've been pulling my hair out with this for the last few hours - turned out that it was my ISPs 'child safe' settings (recently switched to Virgin Media) Hope this helps someone who's tried all the above and still having problems.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting /opt/homebrew directory worked for me.

I am using Macbook air M1

Comment: This is a duplicate because a number of existing answers detail removing `/opt/homebrew`. When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers. Remember to review all existing answers first.

Comment: This works but need to delete all the homebrew directories on your machine

Answer (score 1):

On linux the default installation happens at `/home/linuxbrew`

Just delete the `/home/linuxbrew`: `sudo rm -rf /home/linuxbrew`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/HomeBrew
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/

// actuall command to install HomeBrew
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

If it still doesn't work, try setting you email for git client

```
git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using M1 mac, probably homebrew packages were installed in /opt/.

Try deleting packages like this:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/brew \
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew \          
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1 \
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew \
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew \
rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

On ARM (Mac with Apple Silicon) you should delete the hombrew under /opt

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/
```

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall homebrew with the following code

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

Then uninstall the packages that were installed when trying to install Homebrew by running the following code one by one

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/bin/brew \
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew \          
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1 \
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew \
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew \
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew
```

Finally, go ahead to install homebrew again

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Homebrew and install it again and is gonna work!!

Comment: Since this is the same solution as all the other existing answers recommend, just without code or any other better explanation, I assume that you post this only for saying thanks. In that case please delete this. Otherwise please [edit] to make more obvious what new insight your post contributes to the problem solving. Please consider taking the [tour], it will help you undestand the concepts of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found this very useful

If one sees, 'git  [...] -- [...]' , wait patiently. It's still trying to install

If one sees, Failed during: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet

do /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew update-reset
and reinstall

https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/666

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having to delete the directories, sometimes yo need to do the following:

```
 git config --global --unset http.proxy
 git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

To me was solved by:

`git init`

because I have not initialized a local Git repository, into which this remote is supposed to be added.