# homebrew install error Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force

Tags: git, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I couldn't install homebrew.

Methods I tried:

1. **change http_proxy value** `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:10818;export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:10818;
2. **raise postBuffer value** `git config --global http.postBuffer 5242880000`
3. **change script** using `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` instead of `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL...`  It worked. Can anyone possibly explain why it works? Thanks

Terminal keeps showing this message

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master --tags --force
```

Comment: remove your `/usr/local/Homebrew` and try again

Comment: @Bigman it was removed before I reinstalled brew again. Interestingly, I just tried again via this script `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` instead of `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` It worked.

Comment: @KailiC It work for me :D

Comment: I was having this exact same problem and like you I changed `/bin/bash` at the start of the command to just `bash` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I think we have the same issue and it always breaks when I reached installing homebrew/core:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno
54 fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal:
index-pack failed Failed during: git fetch --force origin
refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I used these resources to solve the problem
[Homebrew install: Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836190/homebrew-install-failed-during-git-fetch-origin-masterrefs-remotes-origin-mas)

https://www.programmersought.com/article/74365494100/

my steps:

1. I deleted all the folders related to Homebrew, you find them at start of install run:
   (put in script and run as you might need to do more than once, like me :/)
   ==> This script will install:

   /usr/local/bin/brew
   /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
   /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
   /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
   /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
   /usr/local/Homebrew
2. I ensured all network connection is ok and I can ping github.com
3. I ensured my email is assigned to account on github

   git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com
4. as you did increase the post buffer value

   git config --global http.postBuffer 5242880000
5. modify the security setting on ssl transfer

   git config  --global   http.sslVerify "false"

Then it all worked and started to download well. I did not break but it was taking a very long time... I remember leaving my MacBook Pro and coming back after a long time and it was still transferring in...I hope I was able to help.

It took me a whole day to solve it but the two links have all the details if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me.  Sorry if my following question is idio-tic: after step 5, do I need to turn this SSL Verify back on? If yes, run "gif config --global http.sslVerify "true"?

Answer (score 1):

I was messing for hours with this and tried all mentioned fixes here and on a few other sites.

This was a simple case of turning on a VPN

Answer (score 0):

in ubuntu 20.04,
go to your file-menu, select "other locations", select "computer", select the "home" folder.
right-click and "open in terminal".

enter "sudo rm -rf linuxbrew".
try the installation again.
If errors still pop out,
enter "git config --global user.email '<your git email'"
now try the installation again.