# Homebrew install error Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin

Tags: homebrew

Below error received while installing Homebrew

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 244358, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (627/627), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (408/408), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 4757 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
Failed during: /usr/bin/git fetch --force origin
```

Answer (score 1):

Below link is very useful [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069083/homebrew-install-error-failed-during-git-fetch-origin-masterrefs-remotes-origi)

**Solution**

1. Solution is if you have good internet connection then ideally you should not face this issue.
2. Still if you are facing issue then follow this simple steps.
3. I ensured my email is assigned to account on github

git config --global user.email yourgitemail@example.com

4. as you did increase the post buffer value

   git config --global http.postBuffer 5242880000
5. modify the security setting on ssl transfer

   git config --global http.sslVerify "false"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked for me.  Sorry if my following question is idio-tic: after step 5, do I need to turn this SSL Verify back on? If yes, run "gif config --global http.sslVerify "true"?

Comment: No need to change SSL to true.