# Homebrew installation failed

Tags: homebrew

I was trying to install Homebrew today on my freshly setup Linux ubuntu. I installed curl and git as usual but when trying to install Homebrew, I got this in my Terminal:

```
david@david-ThinkPad-T460p:~$ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
==> This script will install:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/doc/homebrew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
==> HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE is set to a non-default URL:
... will be used as the Homebrew/brew Git remote.
==> HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE is set to a non-default URL:
... will be used as the Homebrew/homebrew-core Git remote.

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chown -R david:david /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
fatal: '...' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Konnte nicht vom Remote-Repository lesen.

Bitte stellen Sie sicher, dass die korrekten Zugriffsberechtigungen bestehen
und das Repository existiert.

Failed during: git fetch --force origin
```

Can anybody help me with that, as I'm pretty new to the subject and working with Linux at all?

Comment: Looks like it is already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836190/homebrew-install-failed-during-git-fetch-origin-masterrefs-remotes-origin-mas

Answer (score 2):

Run

```bash
unset HOMEBREW_BREW_GIT_REMOTE HOMEBREW_CORE_GIT_REMOTE
```

Then run the installer again