# Homebrew not working on macOS due to invalid version value

Tags: macos, homebrew

whenever I try to use anything brew related, or even just type brew on my computer, this error appears:

```
"/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/version.rb:186:in `initialize': Version value must be a string (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac/version.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/os/mac.rb:15:in `version'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:31:in `<main>'"
```

I am fairly new to developing, so I may be asking a stupid question, and I do not know what to try next.

Answer (score 3):

There are similar questions related to what you have right now. Here are some things that you can try:

Upgrade homebrew, run the following lines in sequence:

```bash
brew update-reset
brew upgrade
```

Or Re-install homebrew:

```bash
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

After doing either options above you can test if homebrew is working by running the following in your terminal:

```bash
brew --version
```

For good measure try running the following after all other steps mentioned:

```bash
brew doctor
```

Comment: I believe that the second answer, reinstalling would work, but I am not currently on an admin account, and I do not have access to one.

Comment: this doesn't work on an intel laptop.  Failed during: git fetch --force origin

Comment: @Joe what is the exact error tho? I am using macos intel laptop.

Comment: @DaleRyan - that is the exact error: "Failed during: git fetch --force origin". Are you running Ventura?

Comment: @Joe Seems try looking into this thread, they had similar error to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836190/homebrew-install-failed-during-git-fetch-origin-masterrefs-remotes-origin-mas

Comment: and also probably this one: https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions/2899