# fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master

Tags: dart, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew. However, the following error happened.

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
Error: Fetching /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart failed!
Error: Some taps failed to update! The following taps can not read their remote branches:   
       dart-lang/dart
This is happening because the remote branch was renamed or deleted.
Reset taps to point to the correct remote branches by running 'brew tap --repair'
Failed during: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew update --force --quiet
```

I have tried to run

```
brew tap --repair
```

but it turned out that `zsh: command not found: brew`
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew tap --repair` ?

Comment: You seem to have 2 issues: 
1) adding brew to path. Solution: export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH" 
2) fixing dart-lang. Solution: brew tap --repair

Answer (score 79):

This worked for me:

```bash
brew tap --repair
brew cleanup
brew update-reset
```

After that I was able to `brew update` without any issues.

Possible culprit:
`dart-lang/dart: changed default branch name from master to main!`

Comment: This helped me with another problematic package, thank you.

Comment: I have a same issue, and it really helps.

Answer (score 69):

I had the same issue.

`dart-lang` seemed to be the culprit.

`brew update-reset` said that everything was up-to-date apart from:

```
==> Fetching /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart...
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
error: Not a valid ref: refs/remotes/origin/main
```

`brew tap --repair` failed like so:

```
fatal: couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/master
Error: Failure while executing; `git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart fetch origin` exited with 128.
```

Running `brew doctor` didn't show up anything pertinent, so some further digging was required.

Heading over to the `dart-lang` repo showed the very error as an issue & in the thread there, a solution:
https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/issues/131#issuecomment-1411094620

So here's the code that Nakji wrote there:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart
git branch -m master main
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart
```

Follow that up with the specific `brew tap --repair dart-lang/dart` which can then do its magic.

Brew is now able to `update`

Comment: this command deleted everything i had in directory brew update-reset!

Comment: Which command do you mean?

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me fix Mopidy, which was giving me some trouble. :)

Answer (score 3):

For me, none of the above solutions worked. I was about to delete and reinstall Homebrew. Then I tried removing the `dart-lang/dart` tap and it worked for me. Just go to the `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps` folder and delete `dart-lang` folder to remove the tap from brew locally.

Answer (score 2):

Try `brew update-reset`, if it does not work, can you paste `brew doctor` output?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart" that is causing the error by running this command:

```bash
rm -rf /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart
```

Source:
[Homebrew install: Failed during: git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n --depth=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836190/homebrew-install-failed-during-git-fetch-origin-masterrefs-remotes-origin-mas)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked for me but mine was located here 
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/dart-lang/homebrew-dart

Answer (score -2):

try

`rm -rf /usr/local/bin/brew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew`

then repeat the installation

Comment: Try what? How about elaborating on what the commands do? I mean, I know it, but others might not.